# Connect to database with eID

Tags: typo3, typo3-6.2.x

I have a little question:

How do I connect an eid script in my extension with the MySQL database? What is the best practise to do so?

Answer (score 0):

This should be a good point to start:

```
<?php

/**
 * @var $TSFE \TYPO3\CMS\Frontend\Controller\TypoScriptFrontendController
 */
$TSFE = \TYPO3\CMS\Core\Utility\GeneralUtility::makeInstance('TYPO3\CMS\Frontend\Controller\TypoScriptFrontendController', $TYPO3_CONF_VARS, 0, 0);
\TYPO3\CMS\Frontend\Utility\EidUtility::initLanguage();

// Get FE User Information
$TSFE->initFEuser();
// Important: no Cache for Ajax stuff
$TSFE->set_no_cache();

$TSFE->checkAlternativeIdMethods();
$TSFE->determineId();
$TSFE->initTemplate();
$TSFE->getConfigArray();
\TYPO3\CMS\Core\Core\Bootstrap::getInstance()->loadConfigurationAndInitialize();

$TSFE->cObj = \TYPO3\CMS\Core\Utility\GeneralUtility::makeInstance('TYPO3\CMS\Frontend\ContentObject\ContentObjectRenderer');
$TSFE->settingLanguage();
$TSFE->settingLocale();

/**
 * Initialize Database
 */
\TYPO3\CMS\Frontend\Utility\EidUtility::connectDB();

?>
```

The eID file must be registered in `ext_localconf.php` as follows:

```
$GLOBALS['TYPO3_CONF_VARS']['FE']['eID_include']['sha1Converter'] = 'EXT:myext/Classes/Eid/myEidFile.php';
```

If you want to use eID to work with Extbase, you should read [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21139769/typo3-extbase-ajax-without-page-typenum) as it is not suggested to use eID for applications where a lot of database requests are necessary.